# How to exchange a number between two processes securely

Tags: c++, security, secure-coding, information-hiding

Here is the sample code for `myapp1` and `myapp2`:

#### myapp1 code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    int secret = 123;
    char buffer[20];
    sprintf(buffer,"%d",secret);

    char *argv[] = { "/bin/myapp2", buffer, 0 };
    char *envp[] =
    {
        "HOME=/",
        "PATH=/bin:/usr/bin",
        0
    };

    int retval = execve(argv[0], &argv[0], envp); 
    printf("return value is: %d\n", retval);
    
    return 0;
}
```

#### myapp2 code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int val = atoi(argv[1]);
    some_process(val);

    return val;
}
```

As you can see I am calling an application, `myapp2`, from `myapp1` using `execve()`. I send a secret number to `myapp2` in its arguments.
`myapp2` does some processing on it and returns the same secret number to the calling program.
Now, my problem is that I want this secret number to be secret from the outside world. the secret number can easily be hacked using the `ps` command.
What I want is that I want to be sure that `myapp2` been called is the original one. If someone replaces it with a `myappfake`, which also returns the same secret number, how do I know I am being fooled?

Basically, I want to make sure that the `myapp2`, from which I am getting response is the genuine one.

Comment: Why not use a pair of *pipes* to pass data back and forth between the two processes?

Comment: Besides, either you have removed it in your example code to simplify it, or you're misunderstand how the `exec*` family of function work. First of all you need a `fork` call to be able to run the first process in parallel. And secondly even if `execve` returned it would return a success/failure indicator of the `execve` call itself, not what the other programmed returned.

Comment: If someone has full access to the machine then you can't guarantee such safety in any way. Using pipes is better than passing secrets as args, but still that is only [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Comment: You could have a look at boost https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html, then there are also platform specific solutions. RPC is an option but possibly overkill for one number.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The sample code shared is just to simplify the code. Actually, myapp1 is a Linux Kernel Module. And myap2 is being called using call_usermodehelper() API. I guess we can't use pipes in this scenario.

Comment: is the Reason COM+ ? or such kind of features ? - I know COM+ is depend on Windows, but I was thinking that COBRA for Java is a Direction to IPC with Application's, that are written in different DSL's. - like native C/C++ and/or mongo.

Answer (score 1):

I would give you a direction to RPC - remote procedure call(s).
This is an old protocol, but I is used by some modern OS like Linux or Windows.
This protocol can be used over a network. So, you are not limited to local station.
And since Linux, and Windows support local (serverless) environments, it is not a problem to test, or extend the protocol (also it is not limited in the number of calls, you can make).
You can crypt or de-crypt all data on each side (application point).
RPC is a old protocol. So, you have to do your own securities. And, you can coding your RPC application's on different platforms, because RPC protocol is not depend on any platform (in the native form).
But you have must store two copies of the function calls (server/client).
If you clever, you can extend your RPC package function growing, and growing without concern about the protocol. It is always the same. So, you are very flexible, if you want to extend your application.